# How to map Entities when [One to Two] Relationship is required?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
class Address { 
  // Properties 
}
class Account
{
  //Other Properties
  Public Address Permanent { get; set; }
  Public Address Current { get; set; }
}
class Other
{
  //Other Properties
  Public Address OtherAddress { get; set; }
}
```

One account has two address Permanent and Current. I can’t use Address class as a complex type because I need a database table for it and to achieve a simpler design.  I have other entities that require Address entity (one to one).

What is standard way to deal with such situation? How do I map these entities?

It would be great if the solution uses Entity Framework Code First Convention to achieve such relation.

Comment: Why not have a type property for Adress class, and build a one to many relationship?

Comment: @erkaner I need two addresses only for an account so one to many relation solves the problem but it should not be the best way to do it as it does not reflect the actual relation.

Comment: There's no such thing as "One to Two" relationships.  What you have here are two separate 1:1 or 1:0..1 relationships.  Unfortunately, you cannot create 1:1 or 1:0..1 relationships in Entity Framework this way.  You can only create 1:Many relationships.  EF only supports 1:1 or 1:0..1 when they share the same primary key.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Thank you for clarifying. I’ll have to make Address Complex Type to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually simplest way to do this is

```
class Address { 
  // Properties 
}
class Account
{
  //Other Properties
  Public int PermanentAddressId {get;set;}
  Public int CurrentAddressId {get;set;}
  Public Address Permanent { get; set; }
  Public Address Current { get; set; }
}
class Other
{
  //Other Properties
  Public int OtherAddressId {get;set;}
  Public Address OtherAddress { get; set; }
}

class AccountMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
  Public AccountMapping()
  {
    ToTable("Account");
    //Others like HasKey
    HasRequired(a=>a.ParmanentAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.PermanentAddressId);
    HasRequired(a=>a.CurrentAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.CurrentAddressId);
  }
}
class OtherMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Other>
{
   public OtherMapping()
   {
     HasRequired(a=>a.OtherAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.OtherAddressId);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not an expert on EF , but I think you can do something like this,

```
 public class Account
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    ...

    public virtual PermanetAddress PermenentAddress {get;set;}
    public virtual CurrentAddress CurrentAddress {get;set;}
  }

  class Address
  {
     //properties
  }

  class PermanetAddress : Address
  {
     [ForeignKey("Account")]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     //properties
     public virtual Account account {get;set;}
  }
  class CurrentAddress : Address
  {
     [ForeignKey("Account")]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     //properties
     public virtual Account account {get;set;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one to many relationship you need to define a class which will contains a list of objects of another class.
For Example I have two entities Student and Standard. And I want that Standard should contains a many Students. In this case I use next code:

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    }

    public class Standard
    {
        public Standard()
        {
            StudentsList = new List<Student>();
        }
        public int StandardId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I need two addresses only for an account so one to many relation solves the problem but it should not be the best way to do it as it does not reflect the actual relation.